# How do I properly add an element around each child element (before and after)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

The title might be a little confusing so I will show an example of what I mean. Say I have some html code like this

```html
<div id="parentElement">
 <div class="A"></div>
 <div class="B"></div>
 <div class="C"></div>
</div>
```

I would then like to append a new element around each element, so it will turn into this

```html
<div id="parentElement">
 <div class="newElem"></div>
 <div class="A"></div>
 <div class="newElem"></div>
 <div class="B"></div>
 <div class="newElem"></div>
 <div class="C"></div>
 <div class="newElem"></div>
</div>
```

Two things to note is that first, there could be multiple children elements like A, B, C, D, E, ... And two, parentElement could have no children in it like

```html
<div id="parentElement">
</div>
```

and if that's the case, one newElem will simply be added.

```html
<div id="parentElement">
 <div class="newElem"></div>
</div>
```

I can do this through a ton of code and a ton of checks and using jQuery's append and before and after and other methods, but I'm wondering if there's a more efficient/clean way of writing it out.

Thanks!

Comment: Please provide us with more details that include what you have tried.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You really don't need any conditionals.

If you use `children()` and loop over them nothing will happen if there are none. If there are - you can use `after(function)` to do the looping  and then finally use `prepend()` for the parent container whether there are children or not

```js
var newElement = '<div class="newElement">New</div>';

$('#parentElement').children().after(function(){
  return newElement;
}).end().prepend(newElement);
```

```css
.newElement{ background:#ccc}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="parentElement">
 <div class="A">A</div>
 <div class="B">B</div>
 <div class="C">C</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

without jquery:

```
function init() {

    var parent = document.getElementById('parentelement');
    for (var i = 0; i < parent.childElementCount; i = i + 3) {
        var newElement = document.createElement('div');
        newElement.appendChild(document.createTextNode('New Element'));
        parent.insertBefore(newElement, parent.children[i]);
        newElement = document.createElement('div');
        newElement.appendChild(document.createTextNode('New Element 2'));
        parent.insertBefore(newElement, parent.children[i + 2]);
    }
}

window.addEventListener('load', init);
```

Comment: What if there are no children? Case #2 in question

Comment: sorry @charlietfl i didn't saw it before, but if there are no childen, you will not believ... , childElementCount will be Zero and the for loop not executed

Answer (score 0):

The approach I'd take, making use of `before()` and `after()`:

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/DrRoach/pen/oNvQwKe)

```
var newElem = "<div class='newElem'></div>";
$('#parentElement div').each(function (index, element) {
    if (index == 0) {
       element.before(newElem); 
    }

    element.after(newElem);
});

if ($('#parentElement div').length == 0) {
    $('#parentElement').html(newElem);
}
```

Comment: What if there are no children? Case #2 in question

Comment: @charlietfl Ah sorry didn't see that part of the question. Updated

Comment: @charlietfl Changed in pen but not on here. Thanks for the friendly heads up :)

Answer (score 0):

with **vanilla** javascript you can do this

```
var parentElement = document.getElementById("parentElement");
// clone children array
var children = Array.prototype.slice.call( parentElement.children )
// get the length of children
var length = children.length;


for(var i = 0;i <= length;i++){
  /*get current child*/
  var currentChild = children[i];
  /*create new element */
  var newElement = document.createElement("div");
  /*give it class*/
  newElement.className = "newElem"
  if(i == length){
    /*append the element if we reach the end of loop*/
    parentElement.appendChild(newElement)
  }else{
    /*use the insertBefore method*/
    parentElement.insertBefore(newElement ,  currentChild)
  }
}
/*log the result working 100%*/
console.log( parentElement )
```

***result we get***
[image]

Comment: What if there are no children? Case #2 in question